# How to create a static variable in python?

Tags: java, python, class, variables, static

I searched a lot for static variables in python but could not find a direct answer
 . Just as java would have a variable defined as static within a class , can the same be done for python?

Comment: You define the variable in the class. Note that python supports the concept of OO, but is not OO. It is multiparadigm.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68672/4278756

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For using static variable you have to use it inside class.

```
 class XYZ:
     value = 3


 print(MyClass.value) //  access it via class name
```

Answer (score 0):

How's

```
class A(object):
    v = 123
```

You access it simply as

```
A.v
```